# Concatenation of strings in a default argument

Tags: python, string, concatenation, default-arguments

This is a piece of my code...

```
def contactMaster(data="",url= str(chosenMaster)+"todolist"):
    print "url: "+url
```

It prints only "todolist" instead of "http://www.mysite.com/blah/1234/todolist"

Why isn't it working??

Comment: How are you calling it, and what is chosenMaster?  If chosenMaster is empty then is should print `url: todolist`.  Please show a complete example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default arguments are evaluated when the function is *defined* not when it is *executed*. So if `chosenMaster` is empty when Python defines `contactMaster`, it will print only `todolist`.

You need to move `str(chosenMaster)` into the function.

See [Default Argument Values](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) in the Python Tutorial for more info. The example there is:

> The default values are evaluated at the point of function definition in the *defining* scope, so that

```
i = 5

def f(arg=i):
    print arg

i = 6
f()
```

> will print `5`.

Comment: Is it possible to declare, but not initialize global variable in python? In the example, in order get it to print 6, would I have to make i=6, then print i?

Comment: @spatara No. In order to get it to print `6`, you'd either have to have it be `6` _before_ the function _definition_ (where it's `5`) or move the evaluation of `i` into the body of the function, which will get executed _after_ `i` has been set to `6`.

Comment: Yep! got it, my program works...I gave it the value I wanted when I declared it :)

Answer (score 1):

The function definition captures the value of `chosenMaster` at the time the function is *declared*, not when the function is *called*.

Do this instead:

```
def contactMaster(data='', url=None):
    if url is None:
        url = str(chosenMaster) + 'todolist'
    print 'url: ' + url
```

Answer (score 0):

Because [default function arguments are determined when the function is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument). Changing `chosenMaster` after the fact will have no effect.